# Compiling c program with disable_irq and enable_irq error can't find lib linux/irq.h

Tags: c, linux, irq

I'm trying to create a C program whose goal is to enable_irq and disable_irq.I have include linux/irq.h like that

```
#include <linux/irq.h>
```

And when I compile :
gcc myProgram.c -o myExecutable

I have the error : fatal error : linux/irq.h no file or folder find

What package I have to install? I'm on archLinux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot disable IRQs from a userspace application. Those functions are only available within the kernel.

Comment: Even if you are in root? You can't interact with irq? by writing the code in assembler also?

Comment: Even if you're root. Disabling interrupts in a userspace application would cause the machine to stop responding to all input.

Comment: You were right, in order to disable some of the IRQ, I updated a new kernel module.